# appsettings.json not read in .Net Core 3.1 in basic Blazor template

Tags: .net-core, blazor, appsettings, blazor-webassembly

I have basically installed the default Blazor WebAssembley template, with .Net Core server.

Ran the app, worked fine, comes with the initial migration for identity which ran and created the database tables so I could create an account login etc.

Changed 1 view file razor file and now the app will not run. In debug mode I can see the it seems to be empty, so the application falls over when it tries to connect to the DB with an empty connection string.

I just ran through the exact same steps on another machine and the same result, yet the only files changed are the appsettings.json and a razor file.

appsettings worked fine, then without changes no longer works. Any suggestions on where to investigate would be appreciated - this is my first step into .Net Core.

[image: debug]

Comment: Can you supply the code for the Startup class and what your json file looks like. Where is the json file and what is it called?

Answer (score 0):

So just in case anyone else comes across this problem. I had the application open in another browser window, although I was not interacting with it.

Once I closed all the browser windows and ran the application again I no longer had the issue.

One thing to note, I am running IIS Express with the option "Do not start browser" so that VS does not keep closing and opening a new browser window.